# spotless-maven-plugin using eclipse-formatter , project in open-jdk8, formatting is failing due to usage of lombok @_ annotation

Tags: maven

**pom.xml content :**

```
</properties>
       <!-- Spotless Java Eclipse settings -->
        <spotless-maven-plugin.version>2.14.0</spotless-maven-plugin.version>
        <eclipse-formatter.version>4.16.0</eclipse-formatter.version>
        <eclipse.formatter.file>${basedir}/.eclipse-formatter.xml</eclipse.formatter.file>
        <eclipse.import.order>java,javax,lombok,org,com,</eclipse.import.order>
        <skidata.license.header.file>${basedir}/.skidata-license-header.txt</skidata.license.header.file>
    </properties>
```

```
  <!-- Formatting : Import order, licence header and so on : mvn spotless:check , mvn spotless:apply -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spotless-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <java>
                        <eclipse>
                            <version>${eclipse-formatter.version}</version>
                            <file>${eclipse.formatter.file}</file>
                        </eclipse>
                        <removeUnusedImports/>
                        <importOrder>
                            <file>${basedir}/.skidata.importorder</file>
                        </importOrder>
                        <licenseHeader>
                            <file>${basedir}/.skidata-license-header.txt</file>
                        </licenseHeader>
                    </java>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check-spotless-java</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

By using above properties and plugin in my project i get this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.14.0:check (check-spotless-java) on project ssp-order: Execution check-spotless-java of goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.14.0:check failed: java.lang.Exception: You are running Spotless on JVM 8, which limits you to google-java-format 1.7.
[ERROR] If you upgrade your JVM to 11+, then you can use google-java-format 1.11.0, which may have fixed this problem.: InvocationTargetException: 19:44: error: as of release 9, '_' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
```

Upgrading JVM version is not a viable option for me , how can i make this work to be able to use underscore character as an identifier.

Comment: Why do you use `@_` annotation (can't find that in the docs?) ? Which version lombok do you use? Apart from that it will be becoming a problem in the future which already know at the moment (shown in the error output)...

Comment: @khmarbaise , this is a valid lombok annotation (although this is experimental) , check this documentation https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX